# Erlang BIF's to delete tuples in list

Tags: list, erlang, parallel-processing, tuples

How can I delete a tuple with key from a list?

```
Ex:

TupleList = [ {apple, {0,0,0}}, {orange, {0,0,0}}, {bannana, {0,0,0}}]
```

Then I need to delete the tuple whos key matches orange.

So I should get back

```
[ {apple, {0,0,0}},  {bannana, {0,0,0}}]
```

Im looking for a BIF instead of a function as I am using right now.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Erlang should be capitalized as "Erlang", not "ERlang"

Comment: Why is it important for you to have a BIF instead of using some of the lists or proplists functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not [BIF](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html) for this. There is [lists:keydelete/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keydelete-3) which is not BIF in contrast of lists:member/2, lists:reverse/2, lists:keymember/3, lists:keysearch/3 and lists:keyfind/3 which are BIFs. Anyway lists:keydelete/3 performs better than [proplists:delete/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#delete-2) because proplists are little bit more tricky. If you would be interested in performance, your own crafted local function or probably [nif](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) would be better solution as well as list comprehension (which should perform same as local function).

Comment: Agreeing with this reply. I'd also consider choosing a different representation for the data structure, depending on how many elements it contains, rather than a BIF: ordering the tuples in the first place could help, or maybe a tree representation.

Comment: Using NIF is probably the most complex way of doing it. Use either one of the builtin modules, dict, gb_trees, ets (or orddict if you really want it as a list) or design your own special structure. Depends on what interface you want.

Comment: Why is it that my function is worse than what you wrote?  [NewHold] = [{N, X} || {N, X} <- Hold, N =/= Who],  Or is it the same thing?

Comment: @user417896: Aside that it should be `NewHold = [{N, X} || {N, X} <- Hold, N =/= Who]` it simply is not BIF and BIF is what you asked for. This lists comprehension is equivalent of non tail recursive local function `delete([], _)->[]; delete([{N, X}|T], Who) when N=/=Who -> [{N,X}|delete(T,Who)]; delete([_|T], Who) -> delete(T, Who).` Version `delete([],_)->[];delete([{Who,_}=L|T], Who)->[L|delete(T,Who)];delete([_|T], Who)->delete(T, Who).` would be faster but negligible. But anyway there is not BIF for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
proplists:delete(orange, TupleList).
```

Answer (score 0):

solution accomplished:

```
[NewHold] = [{N, X} || {N, X} <- Hold, N =/= Who],
```

Comment: `NewList = [T || {K, _} = T <- List, K =/= DelKey].` might give better performance, as it does not rebuild the tuple.